# SQL Mass Sequence Update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with SQL Server 2012, and I have an issue where a Customers Serial Number starts with leading zero's, (eg 0000001) which in turn causes formatting problems when they are exporting their data to third party interfaces via excel. We have tried to discuss making changes to excel, but the client is not willing.

What I need is an "easy" way to update all existing serial numbers on all tables which have a link to Serial Number (Currently 362 tables), to sequence beginning with 1 (eg 0000001 to 1000001).

Comment: Export it as a text, not number

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ttt
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME, 0 AS isProcessed
    into #t
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'UserID';
    DECLARE @iLooper INTEGER;
    DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @dynamicQuery VARCHAR(1024);
    SET @iLooper = 0;
    WHILE (@iLooper = 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @tableName = TABLE_NAME FROM #t WHERE isProcessed = 0;
        IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE #t SET isProcessed = 1 WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName;
            SET @dynamicQuery = 'UPDATE ' + @tableName + ' SET UserID = CONCAT(''1'', SUBSTRING(UserID, 2, 255)) WHERE SUBSTRING(Source, 1, 1) = ''O''';
            exec(@dynamicQuery)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @iLooper = 1;
        END
    END;
DROP TABLE #t;
END
GO
exec ttt
```

Note:
You might need to disable foreign keys and other keys if the column is used for such constraints